# Can I have a touch input received as a general input?

Tags: javascript, php, touch

I’m trying to add a touch input to an online game that I’m running on my website (joysticks and buttons) but I can’t seem to find anyway to have a general input. The game that I’m using is under license, in which the source code itself cannot be modified, so I can’t just replace the original source inputs.

I don’t have any code to post because ive tried a lot of solutions, none of which work.

Comment: How are you providing input to the game now? An example of that code that is allowing joysticks and buttons to work would at least provide a framework to form an answer around.

Comment: It currently uses standard keyboard entries (wad) and mouse clicks. I can't find a working example of joysticks and buttons to link.